# calculating direction of the player to shoot pygame

Tags: python, math, pygame

This is my player class

```
class Player:
    def  __init__(self, image):
        self.rotation_angle = 0

    def rotate(self, keys, left, right):
        if keys[right]:
            self.rotation_angle -= 0.5
        if keys[left]:
            self.rotation_angle += 0.5
        self.rotated_player = pygame.transform.rotate(self.player, (self.rotation_angle))
```

Now based on`self.rotation_angle`, i need to shoot the bullet. So i did the following.

```
class Bullet:
    def __init__(self):
        self.pos = [player1.pos[0], player1.pos[1]]
        self.direction = math.radians(player1.rotation_angle)
        self.bullet = pygame.Surface((5, 20))
        self.rotated_bullet = pygame.transform.rotate(self.bullet, (self.direction))
        self.bullet.fill((100, 200, 120))
        self.time = 0

    def shoot(self):
        self.pos[0] += math.cos(self.direction) * self.time
        self.pos[1] += math.sin(self.direction) * self.time
        self.time += 0.5
```

But this dosent work and the resulting bullet just moves in some random direction. I tried not converting the angle to radians and changing the `self.direction` value for y-axis to negative but it just isn't working. How would i accurately calculate the direction for bullet? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The unit of the angle for the mathematical operations [`math.sin`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html?highlight=sin#math.sin) and [`math.cos`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html?highlight=cos#math.cos) is radian, but the unit of the angel for [`pygame.transform.rotate()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.rotate) is degrees. Furthermore you have to create a [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) with the flag `SRCALPHA` and to fill the surface with the bullet color, before it is rotated:

```py
class Bullet:
    def __init__(self):
        self.pos = [player1.pos[0], player1.pos[1]]
        self.direction = math.radians(player1.rotation_angle)
        self.bullet = pygame.Surface((10, 5), pygame.SRCALPHA)
        self.bullet.fill((100, 200, 120))
        self.rotated_bullet = pygame.transform.rotate(self.bullet, player1.rotation_angle)
        self.time = 0
```

In pygame the y axis points form the top to the bottom. That is the opposite direction than in a usual [Cartesian coordinate system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system). Because of that the y coordinate of the direction has to be inverted:

```py
class Bullet:
    # [...]

    def shoot(self):
        self.pos[0] += math.cos(self.direction) * self.time
        self.pos[1] -= math.sin(self.direction) * self.time
        self.time += 0.5
```

See the example:

[image]

```py
import pygame
import math

pygame.init()
WIDTH, HEIGHT = 500, 500
window = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

class Player():
    def  __init__(self):
        self.rotation_angle = 0
        self.player = pygame.Surface((20, 20), pygame.SRCALPHA)
        self.player.fill((0, 255, 0))
        self.rotated_player = self.player
        self.pos = (WIDTH//2, HEIGHT//2)
        
    def rotate(self, keys, left, right):
        if keys[right]:
            self.rotation_angle -= 0.5
        if keys[left]:
            self.rotation_angle += 0.5
        self.rotated_player = pygame.transform.rotate(self.player, (self.rotation_angle))

class Bullet:
    def __init__(self):
        self.pos = [player1.pos[0], player1.pos[1]]
        self.direction = math.radians(player1.rotation_angle)
        self.bullet = pygame.Surface((10, 5), pygame.SRCALPHA)
        self.bullet.fill((100, 200, 120))
        self.rotated_bullet = pygame.transform.rotate(self.bullet, player1.rotation_angle)
        self.time = 0

    def shoot(self):
        self.pos[0] += math.cos(self.direction) * self.time
        self.pos[1] -= math.sin(self.direction) * self.time
        self.time += 0.5

player1 = Player()

bullets = []
pos = (250, 250)
run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
            bullets.append(Bullet())

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    player1.rotate(keys, pygame.K_LEFT, pygame.K_RIGHT)       

    for bullet in bullets[:]:
        bullet.shoot()
        if not window.get_rect().collidepoint(bullet.pos):
            bullets.remove(bullet)

    window.fill(0)
    window.blit(player1.rotated_player, player1.rotated_player.get_rect(center=player1.pos))
    for bullet in bullets:
        window.blit(bullet.rotated_bullet, bullet.rotated_bullet.get_rect(center=bullet.pos))
    pygame.display.flip()
```

---

See also

[Why aren't any bullets appearing on screen? - pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59126785/why-arent-any-bullets-appearing-on-screen-pygame)
[Shooting a bullet in pygame in the direction of mouse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59977052/shooting-a-bullet-in-pygame-in-the-direction-of-mouse/59980344#59980344)

Comment: Hi thanks for answering. Just a quick question, is "pygame.SCRALPHA" the same as "convert_alpha"?

Comment: @hippozhipos It has the same effect. If you use `pygame.SCRALPHA`, then a surface with per pixel alpha is generated. If you use `convert_alpha`, the surface is generated with out alpha and after that it is converted.